# GtkWarning: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated

Tags: gtk

I downloaded a game that needs to be run through the terminal, and everything seemed to be fine until I got this message:

```
/usr/bin/pypar2:195: GtkWarning: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated
  wTree  = gtk.glade.XML(os.path.join(consts.dirRes, 'win-main.glade'), domain=consts.appNameShort)
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the software. You should report it to the developers. However, it is also only a warning, and not fatal. You can also just ignore it.